# Direct copy of filtered data not working

Tags: vba, excel

I want to copy data from one workbook to another using direct copy to avoid clipboard usage.

```
SourceWS = Workbooks("Src").Worksheets("data src").Range("A1", "J" & lastRow)
DestWS = Workbooks("Dest").Worksheets("Data results").Resize(SourceWS.Rows.Count, SourceWS.Columns.Count)
DestWS.Value = SourceWS.Value
```

(lastrow is defined earlier in macro and works well)

When running macro, I get an error message on line `DestWS = Workbooks("Dest").Worksheets("Data results").Resize(SourceWS.Rows.Count, SourceWS.Columns.Count)` telling `Runtime error '404' Object required` and I have no idea where my mistake is.

Also, additional question, the source data are filtered data and i want to have only them as result data on the destination worksheet, but I am not sure it will do this at the end. Can anyone confirm and help?

Comment: Use `Set x = ...` to affect objects to a variable.

Comment: A **direct value transfer** cannot be performed on filtered data that contains interim hidden rows.

Comment: `Set DestWS = Workbooks("Suivi projets LVV").Worksheets("YOPtool").Resize(SourceWS.Rows.Count, SourceWS.Columns.Count)`doesn't work either @Vincent G , i still have the same error message

Comment: Oh thank you @Jeeped, I didn't know that it would cause issue. Am I then condemned to use Copy/Paste special or is there a workaround?

Comment: You cannot resize a worksheet as a target/destination; only the cells on a worksheet. e.g. ...Worksheets("Data results").**Cells**.Resize(...

Comment: You could copy the whole range to the destination then filter for **not** being your criteria and delete what you don't want.. (you get that you haven't provided much to guess about haven't you?)

Comment: `SourceWS = ... ` means it is not an object, so in the following line you cannot get `SourceWS.Rows...`. You also need `Set SourceWS = ...` on the first line

Comment: Those king of errors probably means that your variables are not properly defined. How did you defined them?

Comment: @Jeeped In fact I just didn't want to have to manipulate data again after copying them on destination worksheet. It works with Copy/Paste Special and I thought I could do the same with direct copy of values. Now I understand it is not as simple as that. If you need more info to help, I'd be happy to provide them

Comment: @Vincent G my only variable in this code is `lastrow`and is defined as follows `lastRow = ActiveSheet.Range("B" & ActiveSheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row` As I use it in many other lines in the macro, I know it is well defined

Comment: in the code you posted, I can see 3 [variables](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/declaring-variables), lastRow being only one of them. The others are SourceWS and DestWS.

Comment: SourceWS and DestWS are defined as Range

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This snippet copies all visible cells to the same position on target sheet, yet leaving empty cells for filtered rows.

```
Dim shSrc As Worksheet, shTrg As Worksheet
Dim cl As Range     ' aux, loop var
Dim rSrc As Range   ' source range
Dim rTrg As Range   ' target range

Set shSrc = WorkBooks("Source.xlsx").Worksheets("source data sheet")
If shSrc Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
Set shTrg = Workbooks("Target.xlsx").Worksheets("Target data sheet")
If shTrg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

Set rSrc = shSrc.Range("A10:M50")
For Each cl In rSrc.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    shTrg.Cells(cl.Row, cl.Column).Value = cl.Value
Next cl
```

Comment: Thanks @AcsEmo! It indeed copies only visible values but it leaves blanks lines for hidden values. Still better than no value copied as I was having with me own code and at least I can deal with blank lines :) Thanks alot for this snippet!

Answer (score 0):

Set objects, resize Cells not worksheets and Copy filtered data then revert any formulas to their resolved values.

```
'assumes filter is already in place
SET SourceWS = Workbooks("Src").Worksheets("data src").Range("A1", "J" & lastRow)
SET DestWS = Workbooks("Dest").Worksheets("Data results")
with SourceWS
    .COPY destination:=DestWS.cells(1)
    DestWS.cells.Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count) = _
      DestWS.cells.Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count).Value
end with
```